# Which is better to create a webapp in which multiple users will sign up for events - Python or Java ?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, web-applications, twitter-bootstrap

I intend to create a webapp in which members of an organization will sign in, filter and search for events, and sign up to attend events. I'm just making this for one organization, but I'll most likely make it open source when I'm done.

I have my own hosting space on GoDaddy, but then I found Google's App Engine and figured it would be more efficient.

I also plan on using Twitter Bootstrap and HTML5 Boilerplate (maybe?). UI is important to me. I'll also make an iPad app with the same function that uses the same data sometime soon.

So Python or Java? What are the advantages and disadvantages for this application for each? I've learned the absolute basics of both languages but have not used either of them for the web.

I'd consider the [Go Programming Language](http://golang.org/), but it doesn't look as community-supported.

TIA!

Comment: Take your pick. Both will work.

Comment: The answer is: the one on which you have more experience. Any programming language can do almost anything... it's a matter of how you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Blender and @Barranka are right. Both languages are equally well supported on App Engine, with only very minor differences. The web client libraries you mention should integrate equally well with either, and you won't easily be able to port code to iOS in either language. (If you also plan an Android app, that might be a vote for Java, but you didn't mention that.)

So the answer is, pick the language you prefer. Both will work.

(If you don't have a preference, maybe lean toward Python, since it's higher level and supports rapid development a bit better, and Java's advantages (performance, static typing, etc.) aren't as important for what you want to build.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll use Python then.

Comment: Static typing is an advantage? I beg to differ.